# How to Change Table on ListView Binding Dynamically

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm generating the GridView dynamically by removing existing columns and adding new ones based on the given table. It shows the data but I'm getting tons of errors in the immediate window.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error: 'MainPartnerName' property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView' (HashCode=39346072)'. BindingExpression:Path=MainPartnerName; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=39346072); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

```
Private Sub SetupGridView(ByVal objTable As Object)
    'remove existing columns
    Dim gv As GridView = lvClientsView.View
    For x As Integer = gv.Columns.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        gv.Columns.RemoveAt(x)
    Next

    'add new column for each column in table
    For Each col As DataColumn In objTable.Columns
        Dim gvCol As GridViewColumn = Nothing
        gvCol = New GridViewColumn
        gvCol.Header = col.ColumnName
        gvCol.DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding(col.ColumnName)
        gv.Columns.Add(gvCol)
    Next

    Dim bnd As New Binding
    bnd.Source = objTable
    lvClientsView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, bnd)

End Sub
```

My XAML is simple:

```
<ListView Name="lvClientsView" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  >
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="lvClientsViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"  />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I'm dynamically dismantling and rebuilding the view. How can i remove the table and the binding so I can assign a different table and binding?

Comment: Why is objTable an object? You don't have a specific class for it?

Comment: @Isma I have two different tables with differing column names. So my question is "How do I remove everything associated with the first table so it can rebuild from the ground up"?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I discovered I need to do four things:

1. Set new blank binding with no data
2. Remove existing GridView and replace with new one
3. Add new columns per new table definition
4. Set binding to new table

   ```
   Private Sub SetupGridView(ByVal objTable As Object)

       'set binding to new blank binding with no data
       lvClientsView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, New Binding)

       'remove existing gridview and replace with new one
       lvClientsView.View = Nothing
       Dim gv As New GridView
       lvClientsView.View = gv

       'add new column for each column in table
       For Each col As DataColumn In objTable.Columns
           Dim gvCol As GridViewColumn = Nothing
           gvCol = New GridViewColumn
           gvCol.Header = col.ColumnName
           gvCol.DisplayMemberBinding = New Binding(col.ColumnName)
           gv.Columns.Add(gvCol)
       Next

       'set new binding to objTable
       Dim bnd As Binding = New Binding
       bnd.Source = objTable
       lvClientsView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, bnd)

   End Sub
   ```

   Works beautifully!